# Are there any free news APIs?

Tags: api, news

Over the past few years, I have managed to find all sorts of excellent data sources across the web, almost always for free, including static data (e.g. `.csv`), but also plenty of free APIs, for example finance, weather, sport etc.

But I have not been able to find a free news API.

#### Question

My question is: where can we find a free and simple news API, with a preference for

- As many news articles as possible
- Going back as far as possible

#### What I've tried

It is well known that Google is an excellent aggregator of news. However, it is notoriously difficult to web scrape (they have a paid news API - not a free one).

Answer (score 0):

you can use hacker news api particularly for tech news

Comment: can you add more info, including uris please?